# ant.propertyFile updates comment everytime

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle, properties

In my `build.gradle` file I have the following variable to indicate which environment I'm building to:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.5.15.RELEASE'
        kotlinVersion = '1.2.70'
        queryDslVersion = '4.1.4'
        env = 'local'
    }
    // ...
}
```

And on my `application.properties` I have the following line for spring to use the correct `application-{env}.properties`:

```
spring.profiles.active=local
```

I have created a gradle task to update this value on my `application.properties` as follow:

```
task setEnv {
    doFirst {
        ant.propertyfile(file: "$projectDir/src/main/resources/application.properties") {
            entry( key: "spring.profiles.active", value: "$env")
        }
        println "Building with env = $env"
    }
}
```

The task works just fine except it adds one comment line with the timestamp of the update. So my `application.properties` now looks like:

```
#Fri, 14 Dec 2018 11:22:04 -0200
spring.profiles.active=local
```

This is a problem because everytime someone builds the project it changes this file, causing conflicts when commiting and pushing to git.

Any ideas on how I could get rid of that comment? Or even a better approach to set spring profile?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible with ant, because it's implemented with the `java.util.Properties` class and it's said in the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#store-java.io.Writer-java.lang.String-) that:

> ...a comment line is always written, consisting of an ASCII #
>   character, the current date and time (as if produced by the toString
>   method of Date for the current time), and a line separator as
>   generated by the Writer.

So, to avoid it, you have to change a value in your properties file in some other way. For example, by configurion the [`ProcessResources` Gradle task](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/language/jvm/tasks/ProcessResources.html) as follows:

```
processResources {
  filesMatching('**/*.properties') {
    filter {
        it.replace('@ENV@', "$env")
    }
  }
}
```

And the value should be set to `@ENV@` inside the `application.properties`

Comment: Thanks, it worked like a charm. And it is even better because it changes the property only in the built file!